# だから/から and なので/ので when used with anything but nouns and なadjectives

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between なので and ので when used in anything but nouns and な adjectives. For example:

> 行かない**なので**他の誰かを頼んで

> 行かない**ので**他の誰かを頼んで

I assume that a similar explanation holds for だから and から

Answer (score 2):

"なので" is ungrammatical when used with anything other than a noun or な adjective, so only the second example you wrote is valid. You are correct that だから and から function in the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure about it being ungrammatical because I saw an anime that used ....ないなのに......

Comment: Are you sure that's what was being said? The correct phrasing in that situation would be ないのに. If you do a simple concordance search in Google, you'll find that [there are no hits in which "ない" is followed by "なのに."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB%E2%80%9D&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS853US853&oq=%22%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB%E2%80%9D&aqs=chrome..69i57.5540j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). On the other hand, there are hundreds of millions of examples of "ないのに."

Comment: @Newbie Some characters speak in an idiosyncratic ways in anime. If you are REALLY sure someone said ないなのに in the anime, that means you should not learn from her/his way of speaking.

Comment: @naruto Yea,  rechecked a couple of times and indeed said　...ないなのに....　Heard it from a pretty famous anime called "My hero academia", so I'd thought it will be grammatically right

Comment: @Newbie I'm interested to it. Could you point me to the exact scene that expression used? It seems that anime really has some characters who speak broken Japanese, or maybe just wrong parsing on your side.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Maybe it was 「…ない。なのに…」.

Comment: I'm under the impression that "ない” can be used as a noun, something like the no-ness? As seen in these examples: https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9197

Comment: @nayfaan Those examples are grammatically just adj. ない modifying a (formal) noun よう, which in turn makes up ようだ that is functionally an auxiliary verb. If you want to tell "no-ness" you'd say なさ.