# Is ばかり a noun or a な-adjective in ばかりなので?

Tags: adverbs, particle-な, particle-ばかり, adverbial

According to [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/75191/32952) and taking into account the following rules ([source](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/5656968#answer-15048955)) to use ので:

- [い-adjective]+ので
- [verb]+ので
- [な-adjective]+なので
- [noun]+なので

I wonder whether ばかり is a な-adjective or not in the following sentences:

> 海外で一人暮らしを始めた**ばかりなので**、寂しくてしかたがありません。

> 子どもを産んだ**ばかりなので**、うちで休んでいるところです。

Comment: https://www.weblio.jp/content/ばかり
ばかり is categorized as an adverb.

Comment: @nayfaan Thank you for your help!I wonder if you know the meaning/reason  of  な being there in the sentence?

Comment: Actually, ばかり is categorized not as an adverb, but as an adverbial particle (the abbreviation 副助 stands for 副助詞). I think the assertion that なので can only be used with a noun or a な adjective is simply an overgeneralization. The な in なので is the 連体形 of だ, so 子どもを産んだばかりなので seems just as grammatical as 子どもを産んだばかりだ. That said, it is *not* the case that all adverbial particles can be used with だ or なので in this way, so while I think your premise is incorrect, I wonder if maybe there is in fact something "nounlike" about ばかり in usages like this. I hope someone will answer your question & address that.

Comment: @Nanigashi So な in なので is the 連体形 of だ. It's a new useful information for me! I appreciate it!
`I wonder if maybe there is in fact something "nounlike" about ばかり` Does this mean you are looking for the 'noun-ish' feature of ばかり so that it fits well with なので? Although you said `the assertion that なので can only be used with a noun or a な adjective is simply an overgeneralization.` ?

Comment: Right – だ and by extension なので *can* be used with ばかり and at least a few other 副助詞 (e.g., まで and だけ), but there are other 副助詞 that they *can't* be used with (e.g., さえ, なんて). So I wonder if that means there's something special about the subset of 副助詞 that だ *can* be used with – some nounlike quality or other characteristic that allows this pairing with だ, even though the words aren't in fact nouns. Again, it's not a question I'm qualified to answer, and someone more qualified might say that even the question itself doesn't make any sense. (I'm neither a linguist nor a native speaker.)

Comment: Actually, in the [link to weblio](https://weblio.jp/content/ばかり) posted by nayfaan , it states that ばかり is a 副助 and it connects to 名詞, 副詞, 活用語の**連体形** and 一部の助詞. It is then congruent with Nanigashi's explanation that な is the 連体形 for だ.

Comment: @raruna, ばかり is derived from はかり, the 連用形 of verb はかる "to measure". The basic sense progression was something like "a full measure [of whatever came before]", then shifting in some usages to something like "a full measure [of whatever came before], and _only_ [whatever came before]", with that sense of limitation coming in. Compare くらい, also derived from a 連用形 conjugation, originally from 座【くら】 + 居【ゐ】.

Answer (score 1):

The word "ばかり" in Japanese is not an adjective (な-adjective or い-adjective) but a particle or auxiliary that is often used to express the meaning of "just" or "only." It's used to indicate that something has just occurred or is limited to something specific.

In your examples:

海外で一人暮らしを始めたばかりなので、寂しくてしかたがありません。
(Because I have just started living alone overseas, I am so lonely.)

子どもを産んだばかりなので、うちで休んでいるところです。
(Because I have just given birth to a child, I am resting at home.)

In both sentences, "ばかり" is attached to the past tense of a verb (始めた, 産んだ) to indicate that the action of starting to live alone or giving birth has just been completed. The structure [verb in past tense]+ばかり is then followed by "なので" to provide a reason or cause, consistent with the usage of "なので" after nouns and な-adjectives.

So, "ばかり" is not categorized as a な-adjective; rather, it functions as a particle or auxiliary that modifies a verb.

Hope it helps.